# How many comic-based movies won an Oscar?

Tags: movie, comics

I'm curious to know how many movies based on **any** comic source have **won** an Oscar(s). This can range from the massive Marvel or DC universe comics to individual comics such as Men in Black (originally written by Lowell Cunningham of Malibu before Marvel bought their souls), or to include comic strips (such as Dick Tracy which originated as a strip, not a book).

I have found only 6 movies which have won at least one:

- Superman - Best Visual Effects (1979)
- Batman - Best Art Direction (1989)
- Dick Tracy - Best Original Song, Best Makeup & Best Art Direction (1990)
- Men In Black - Best Makeup (1997)
- Spider-Man 2 - Best Visual Effects (2004)
- The Dark Knight - Best Supporting Actor & Best Sound Editing (2008)

Are these the only ones?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_based_on_English-language_comics

Comment: I do know that a lot of great films, like *Barb Wire* and *Howard the Duck*, have been snubbed by the Academy.

Comment: @KSmarts - Barbwire was a great film? In which universe? Some of the most wooden acting since Pinocchio.

Comment: Also, technically the Superman (1979) award was an achievement award, as Best Visual Effects was not a category at the time. I don't believe achievement awards count as Academy Awards (i.e. an Oscar).

Comment: http://www.comicbookmovie.com/fansites/ComicReel/news/?a=55488

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Academy_Award-winning_films

Comment: Watchmen friggin' shoulda...

Comment: Why is this closed? The list the OP is asking about is a finite one with well defined criteria (unlike a recommendation list). Voting to reopen.

Comment: @SystemDown, thanks for the support! I also don't understand why it's been placed on hold since I think I pretty much mentioned most of them...

Comment: "*any comic source"*? Including those that aren't science fiction or fantasy? Sounds off-topic to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only other one that I know of is [*Road to Perdition*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_to_Perdition) (2002), which won the an Oscar for Best Cinematography.

Comment: Cool! Loved this film, never knew it was a graphic novel originally. I will mark this as accepted if nobody else posts anymore (which I doubt anyone will since it's placed on hold!)